# How can I use data in realm from another class? (android)

Tags: android, realm

This is method stopPing() in MainActivity to save data to realm.
If I want to use data in realm from another class, how can I coding.

```
private  void stopPing() {
    linkEdt.setEnabled(true);
    pingBtn.setText("Start Ping");
    isPing = false;
    count = 0;

    endTime = getTime();

    /* Open the Realm for the UI thread. */
    realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);

    /* All writes must be wrapped in a transaction to facilitate safe multi threading */
    realm.beginTransaction();

    Ping ping = realm.createObject(Ping.class);

    /* Add ip */
    ping.set_ip(ip);

    /* Add start time */
    ping.set_startTime(startTime);

    /* Add end time. */
    ping.set_endTime(endTime);

    /* Add down amount */
    ping.set_downAmount(downtime);

    /* Add ping speed time. */
    PingTime pingtime = realm.createObject(PingTime.class);

    for(Double speedTime : speedList){
        pingtime.time = speedTime;
        ping.get_times().add(pingtime);
    }

    /* Add time. */
    for(String time : timeList){
        pingtime.pingTime = time;
        ping.get_pingTime().add(pingtime);
    }

    realm.commitTransaction();

    /* stop handler. */
    this.mHandler.removeCallbacks(m_Runnable);
}
```

When I want to query in another class it has error with realm -->> io.realm.Realm.allObjects(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ping_list);


    for (Ping pers : realm.allObjects(Ping.class)) {

        String startT, endT;
        if (pers.get_stratTime() == null) {
            startT = "None";
        } else {
            startT = pers.get_stratTime();
        }

        if (pers.get_endTime() == null) {
            endT = "None";
        } else {
            endT = pers.get_endTime();
        }

        status += "Start time: " + startT + "\n End time: " + endT + "\n";
        status += "Ping total: " + pers.get_times().size() + "\n";
        status += "Down amount: " + pers.get_downAmount() + " time.\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < pers.get_times().size(); i++) {
            double speed = pers.get_times().get(i).time;
            String time = pers.get_pingTime().get(i).pingTime;

            status += "time (" + (i + 1) + "): " + speed + " ms. at " + time + ".\n";
        }

    }

    System.out.println(status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the realm instance in the 2nd class? If you didn't call `realm = Realm.getInstance(...)` the variable will be null, resulting in the NullPointerException you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks. I have use.

` realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig); `

but, it didn't work.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A non-null RealmConfiguration must be provide

Comment: You can see here how to create and use a RealmConfiguration: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/introExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/intro/IntroExampleActivity.java#L55-Lundefined